# Any standard heuristic to solve non-convex polygon (with holes) covering problem?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a non-convex region (may contain holes). I want to:

1. Fill region with rectangles
2. No restriction on size or number of rectangles
3. Maximize the area occupied by rectangles
4. Minimize number of rectangles
5. Avoid rectangle overlap
6. Have rectangle axes aligned with bounding box's axes

Are there standard heuristic approaches to solve this optimization? How would you formally classify this problem?

Read through various cutting stock problem literature, but didn't find something quite similar.

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp! Is your region given by polygonal lines, or can it also be round?

Comment: If your region is not also axis-aligned you'll need infinite rectangles (which is a pretty good band name).

Comment: Hi, Thank you @MPIchael :) The region and its holes are made of polygonal lines. Hi Richard, the region is axis aligned.

Answer (score 1):

You overlay your region with a grid of squares. You mark all squares that are entirely in the region as black, all squares entirely outside of the region as white and all squares partially in the region as grey. (One sweep: $\mathcal{O}(n)$). You then subdivide all grey squares into four (or eight in 3D) smaller squares. You again sweep all grey squares (Another sweep: $\mathcal{O}(n)$) in the same manner. When you have done a number of sweeps like this, you can join squares together with their neighbours if one of their sides is completely covered by smaller squares, or by a neighbour of equal size. If you can no longer join any squares with its neighbours you are done.

This might not be the best algorithm, but I would assume that it can be easily implemented and parallelized and can be easily reasoned about when talking about convergence rates. The hard thing will be to define what 'outside' really is.

[image: First sweep, marking inside,outside and partially inside.]